# comparing a variable int that have multiple number without being an array

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az0gN.png)

so i have this problem to solve it's working without any errors but the number of a and f isn't right they give me a false answer. the photo show the problem and we can't calculate f and a in the method **genarategrades**

```
    static int genarategrades(int n) {
    int a = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a = (int) (Math.random() * (100 - 50)) + 50;

        System.out.print(a + " ");

    }
    return a;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a positive value for n: ");
        n = input.nextInt();
    } while (n <= 0);

    System.out.print("Genarate Grades: ");
    int grade = genarategrades(n);
    int A = 0;
    int F = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < grade; i++) {
        if (grade < 60) 
            F++;
        else if (grade > 90) 
            A++;


    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("NB of A students: " + A);
    System.out.println("NB of F students: " + F);

    System.out.println("Percentage A: " + A + "/" + n + " = " + (double) A / n);
    System.out.println("Percentage F: " + F + "/" + n + " = " + (double) F / n);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `genarateGrades()` inside the loop if you don't want to use an array, like this:

```
   static int genarateGrades(int n) {
        int a = 0;
        a = (int) (Math.random() * (100 - 50)) + 50;
        System.out.print(a + " ");
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a positive value for n: ");
            n = input.nextInt();
        } while (n <= 0);

        System.out.print("Generated Grades: ");
        int A = 0;
        int F = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int grade = genarateGrades(n);
            if (grade < 60)
                F++;
            else if (grade > 90)
                A++;
        }

        input.close();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("NB of A students: " + A);
        System.out.println("NB of F students: " + F);

        System.out.println("Percentage A: " + A + "/" + n + " = " + (double) A / n);
        System.out.println("Percentage F: " + F + "/" + n + " = " + (double) F / n);
    }
```

, output

```
Enter a positive value for n: 5
Generated Grades: 59 75 80 98 79
NB of A students: 1
NB of F students: 1
Percentage A: 1/5 = 0.2
Percentage F: 1/5 = 0.2
```